# Do the actions in XCode's edit scheme window belongs to the scheme?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

In **Xcode**'s *edit scheme window* , we can see these *actions*(**Build**,**Run**...) ,and it seems those **actions** belongs to a **Scheme**.
But in **scheme's** official  `definition` :

> An **Xcode** scheme defines a **collection** of *targets to build*, a
> **configuration** to use when **building**, and a *collection of tests* to
> **execute**.

seems the **scheme** doesn't contains these **actions**. so what are those actions and How do those **actions work** ?